# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] for two Drupal jQuery Plugins

Tags: jquery, drupal, plugins, typeerror

I'm using Drupal 7 mothership theme and installed views accordion and nivo slider.  On the views page where I can preview the content that will be published to the block and the page, I see the accordion works there, however on the actual page, I get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion' and on the home page that has the nivo slider I get Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'nivoSlider'.  My guess is I have two versions of jQuery running at the same time or the files may not be in the right order.

I'm not sure but from what I see in the core directory, jQuery 1.4.4 is for the core files and I jave jQuery 1.8.3(which is the script.js?mg3zbe file, second to last) and if I take 1.4.4 out of the site I get a bunch of jQuery is undefined for core and if I take jQuery 1.8.3 out of the theme, I get undefined for my greyscale-fade plugin and then that breaks.

I'm not sure what to do and how I can reorder the jQuery files in Drupal. In my .info file, I just have to js files

;-------------- JS -------------

scripts[] = js/script.js

scripts[] = js/greyscale-fade.js

[image]

I'm hoping someone can point out what's wrong and a solution for this. It's driving me crazy.

Here is also a screen shot to show I do have the accordion setup correct so I can rule that out.
[image]

Comment: jQuery 1.8.7 doesn't exist.... what are you actually referring to? If you really meant 1.8.3, remove 1.4.4 and place 1.8.3 in it's place. Most likely at that point you will run into a few compatibility issues that you'll have to work through by updating plugins.

Comment: [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download/) might help

Comment: my mistake it is 1.8.3, I tried what you said and it still displays the same error.